# what is the problem with this code because it is not listening the state changes

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, state-management

I am using flutter_bloc library and HydratedBloc to create Auth bloc. The problem here is that BlocListener is not listening to state changes,

so please let me know what I am missing in this code?

*(what I think is that the initial state will be returned from the function ‘fromJson’but it does not emit new state)* Here is what I tried to do

```
        class App extends StatelessWidget {
          const App({super.key});
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return MultiBlocProvider(
                providers: [
                  BlocProvider(create: (context) => AuthBloc()),
                ],
                child: MaterialApp(
                  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                  theme: Themes.light,
                  darkTheme: Themes.dark,
                  themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
                  title: AppContants.appName,
                  navigatorKey: NavigationService.navigatorKey,
                  onGenerateRoute: Routes.navigateTo,
                  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
                    child = EasyLoading.init()(context, child);
        
                    return BlocListener<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
                        listener: (context, AuthState state) {
                          //bloc listener is used to make a actions instead of builds
                          //bloc bulder is used to return a widget
                          print('state is $state');
                          if (state is AuthAuthenticatedState) {
                            // NavigationService.navigateAndRemoveUntil(Confirm.route);
        
                            NavigationService.navigateAndRemoveUntil(
                              Dashboard.route,
                            );
                          } else {
                            NavigationService.navigateAndRemoveUntil(Login.route);
                          }
                        },
                        child: child);
                  },
                ));
          }
        }
        
        
    
    class AuthBloc extends HydratedBloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> {
          AuthBloc() : super(AuthInitial()) {
            on<AuthAuthenticatingEvent>(authAuthenticating);
            on<AuthUnAuthenticatingEvent>(authUnAuthenticating);
          }
        
          authAuthenticating(event, emit) async {
            await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
            emit(const AuthAuthenticatedState(''));
          }
        
          authUnAuthenticating(event, emit) {}
        
          @override
          AuthState? fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
            String? token = json['token'];
            if (token != null && token.isNotEmpty) {
              return AuthAuthenticatedState(token);
            }
        
            return AuthUnAuthenticatedState();
          }
        
          @override
          Map<String, dynamic>? toJson(AuthState state) {
            if (state is AuthAuthenticatedState) {
              return {'token': state.token};
            }
            return {};
          }
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `AuthAuthenticatingEvent` to the `AuthenticationBloc`, e.g. with

```
BlocProvider(create: (context) => AuthBloc()..add(AuthAuthenticatingEvent()))
```

Otherwise your Bloc will not call `authAuthenticating(event, emit)`.

Or are you already making this call somewhere in your code? In that case, you should add it to your question.